# wait the execution of foreach to continue next in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic2, wait

I'm trying to use the values of an array list after executing the for loop.

My problem is that when I run my application, it executes the next functions without waiting my for loop

This is my TS code,

```
convertToPDF(){
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: "Generating..."
    })
    loader.present().then(_=>{
        this.TempNotesImagesList.forEach(n=>{
            this.convertToDataURLviaCanvas(n.url, "image/jpeg").then(base64Img => {
                this.images.push(base64Img);
            });
        })
    }).then(_=>{
        loader.dismiss();
        console.log(this.images); //Check images
        this.createPdfX(); //convert to PDF :D
    });

}
```

Comment: so you want to run asynchronous in series, not parallel ... try simple promise chaining

Comment: does `this.images` really need all the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you need the `convertToDataURLviaCanvas` to run in series or parallel?

Series:

```
convertToPDF() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: "Generating..."
    });
    loader.present()
    .then( _ => this.TempNotesImagesList.reduce((p, n) => p.then(_ => this.convertToDataURLviaCanvas(n.url, "image/jpeg").then(base64Img => {
        this.images.push(base64Img);
    })), Promise.resolve())).then(_ => {
        loader.dismiss();
        console.log(this.images); //Check images
        this.createPdfX(); //convert to PDF :D
    });
}
```

Parallel:

```
convertToPDF() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: "Generating..."
    });
    loader.present()
    .then( _ => Promise.all(this.TempNotesImagesList.map(n => this.convertToDataURLviaCanvas(n.url, "image/jpeg").then(base64Img => this.images.push(base64Img)))))
    .then(_ => {
        loader.dismiss();
        console.log(this.images); //Check images
        this.createPdfX(); //convert to PDF :D
    });
}
```

Comment: Finally I knew how to make this.. thank u v.much .. i didn't know the solution easy like this