# Ionic: How is promise working?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I tried to change my forEach to an .reduce to use Promise.
My Code is

```html
getResolvedData(arrInsertedData){
        let arrData = [];
        let that = this;

        arrInsertedData.reduce((p, objInsertedData) => p.then(_ =>  {
            let arrDataLength = arrData.length;

            that.getNewData(objInsertedData).then(arrNewData => {
                arrData[arrDataLength] = arrNewData;
            })
        }), Promise.resolve().then(_ => function (arrData) {
            return Promise.resolve(arrData);
        }));
    }
```

It is always returning nothing. So how could I do it correctly?

Comment: I didn't get what you're trying to do. But so far I can tell that getResolvedData() does not return anything.

Comment: I want to return my new data written in the array arrData AFTER writing the new data.

Comment: there is no way to do that, you could use `async/await` syntax to make your code more readable, but in the end your getResolvedData function will always be asynchronous (returning a Promise or taking a callback as last parameter)

Comment: But there have to be a way that I return it just after it got filled? How do I do it?

Comment: you don't "return" results from an asynchronous function. You define a callback function that handles the result of your asynchronous function. If you're using asynchronous functions in your code you're "stuck" with it and there is no way to make a synchronous function that returns results from asynchronous functions

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ? The code you posted is in a service ? a component ?

Comment: I am just trying to wait for my foreach is finished. I changed it to .reduce because i read it in another thread. But it seems, that that is the wrong solution for my problem. I want to wait until foreach(reduce) is finished and then return my result.

Comment: all i have to do is to wish you good luck 

Comment: I´d like to have something like that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908366/wait-the-execution-of-foreach-to-continue-next-in-ionic-2
I want to wait until my loop is executed and THEN return back my results. I think I couldn´t really explain it that good, but I hope you understand what I want to do a little bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172181/discussion-between-youkouleley-and-eldiabolo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to work like this. Promises usually resolve asynchronously, so your function will already have returned when `arrData` was populated. You need to handle data in a callback (or use async/await, but you should read up on Promises first).

Also it doesn't look like you need to resolve those promises in order. If they can be resolved in parallel, you should rather use map and Promise.all:

```
getResolvedData(arrInsertedData){    
  Promise.all(
    arrInsertedData.map(objInsertedData => this.getNewData(objInsertedData));
  ).then(arrData => {
    // do something with arrData here
    console.log(arrData);
  });
}
```

You seem to be lacking a basic understanding of Promises, so I suggest you read this

https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies

Don't be offended by the title!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I´m using this, I don´t get any response again. How do I have to modify your answer to use it like mine aboth?

Comment: The function doesn't return anything, you can't achieve what you want to do with a function return (unless you're using async/await which is nothing but Promise sugar). I'm serious, please take the 20 minutes and read up on promises.